# Is using of subqueries more efficient than using Limit offset and order by in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, rdbms

For instance, we have a problem of finding the employee with the second highest salary in the table.
This is my table

```
id  name    dept    salary
1   Ram     HR      10000
2   Amrit   MRKT    20000
3   Ravi    HR      30000
4   Nitin   MRKT    40000
5   Varun   IT      50000
```

Then I would write a subquery like this.

```
select e_name,salary from employee
    where salary = (select max(salary) from employee
                    where salary <> (select max(salary) from employee));
```

And I would use limit and offset like this:

```
select e_name, salary from employee order by salary desc limit 1 offset 1;
```

Which of the following would be more efficient? and why?

Comment: What about ties?

Comment: Vérace asks a good question since if the top two had the same salaries, your two solutions will produce different results.

Comment: @KirkWoll Its just an example, it does not have to be salary, lets say it is an unique field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a lot of variables when it comes to performance and query tuning, so there's no guaranteed answer to which one will be more performant for *your* data at any given time without testing and observing their query plans.

But in general, the second example using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` is likely to be more efficient since it only queries the `employee` table once as opposed to three times in your first example.